# Node.js spawn with Java

Tags: java, node.js

I am trying to build on the following code to make node to run a java program. But there is nothing happening at all and I really do not know how to debug.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/java_preview', function (req, res) {

   console.log("Request for java_preivew:");
   console.log(req.body.url);                 //LINE X
   console.log(req.body.tableparserClass);    //LINE Y

   var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
   var java = spawn('java', ['-version']);
   java.stdout.on('data', function(data) {  //LINE A
      console.log(data);                    //LINE B
      //io.emit('chat message', data.toString())
   });
```

When post requests '/java_preview', line X and Y both works. But then there is no more output on the server's console. When debugging using node-inspector, I put a break point at line A and B. But Line B was not called.

Any suggestions please

many thanks

Answer (score -1):

OK it seems that the output is never sent to the 'stdout' event but 'stderr'. Replacing java.stdout.on with java.stderr.on fixed the problem, even if java exits withs status 0.

I am not sure why this happens.